# In MongoDB, how do I create a custom role using Java?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using MongoDB v7.0.7 with a Java interface.  I am attempting to create a custom user role as follows:

```
public static BasicDBObject createUserCollectionRole( MongoDatabase md, String userCollectionName ) {   
        BasicDBObject resource1 = new BasicDBObject()
                                .append("db",md.getName())
                                .append("collection",userCollectionName);
        
        BasicDBObject privileges = new BasicDBObject()
                                .append("resource",resource1)
                                .append("actions",List.of("find","insert","remove","update"));
        
        BasicDBObject roles = new BasicDBObject()
                                .append("role","readWrite")
                                .append("db",md.getName());
        
        BasicDBObject role = new BasicDBObject()
                                .append("role",userCollectionName)
                                .append("privileges",List.of(privileges))
                                .append("roles",List.of(roles));
        System.out.println(">>role>>> " +role.toString());
        
        BasicDBObject createRole = new BasicDBObject("createRole",role);
        md.runCommand(createRole);
        
        return role;
    }
```

but I get the error:

```
 com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 40414 (Location40414): 'BSON field 'createRole.privileges' is missing but a required field'
```

"privileges" is certainly there and the printed output from my routine (role.toString()) shows this:

```
{
  "role": "user1colln",
  "privileges": [
    { "resource": { "db": "mydb", "collection": "user1colln" },
      "actions": [ "find", "insert", "remove", "update" ] }
  ],
  "roles": [
    { "role": "readWrite", "db": "mydb" }
  ]
}
```

If I insert this output into db.createRole() in Mongosh however, it works. What do I have to do to get it working in Java?